# Unable to pass react router state from Route to child component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-props

React Router V5

I'm trying to build a simple redirect so that when a user tries to access a restricted url, it will redirect them to login and after login, it will send them back to the url they were on. Example: website.com/settings is protected so redirect to login if not already. Once logged in, redirect back to settings. This was working until I recently re-nested my routes to include layouts. I'm assuming my redirect URL is making it to the parent route but I'm not sure how to pass it down to the  component.

App.js:

```
                 <Switch>
                      <Route path="/password-reset/:reset_key?" exact>
                          <AuthLayout>
                              <PasswordReset />
                          </AuthLayout>
                      </Route>
                      <Route path="/register" exact>
                          <AuthLayout>
                              <Register />
                          </AuthLayout>
                      </Route>
                      <Route path="/login" exact>
                          <AuthLayout>
                              <Login />
                          </AuthLayout>
                      </Route>
                      {/* Other MainLayout routes */}
                      <Route>
                          <MainLayout>
                              <Switch>
                                  <Route path="/" exact component={Dashboard} />
                                  <Route path="/search" exact component={SearchResults} />
                                  <Route path="/user/:user_id" exact component={Profile} />
                                  <PrivateRoute path="/settings" exact component={Settings} />
                                  <Route path="/communities" exact component={CommunityDashboard} />
                                  <PrivateRoute path="/communities/new" exact component={CommunityNew} />
                                  <Route path="/communities/view/:community_id" exact component={CommunityView} />
                                  <PrivateRoute path="/communities/edit/:community_id" exact component={CommunityEdit} />
                                  <Route path='/404' component={Error404} />
                              </Switch>
                          </MainLayout>
                      </Route>
                      <Redirect from='*' to='/404' />
                  </Switch>
```

Hitting a protected route, will trigger the PrivateRoute function:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, path, auth, ...rest}) => (
<Route
{...rest}
render = {props =>
    auth.isAuthenticated === true ? (
        <Component {...props} />
    ) : (
        <Redirect to={{
            pathname: '/login',
            state: {
                redirectUrl: window.location.href.includes('login') ? '/' : window.location.href
            }
        }} />
    )
}
/>
```

);

I'm unable to access this.state.redirectUrl anywhere in my code. This is the layout page I am working with. Being the first nested component within the route, I though I'd at least see it there

```
import React  from 'react';
import './auth.css';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {connect} from "react-redux";

class AuthLayout extends React.Component {

componentDidMount() {
    if(this.props.auth.isAuthenticated){
        this.props.history.push('/');
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="auth-background">
            <img
                alt=""
                className="logo"
                src={require("./logo1.png")}
            />
            <div id='auth-form'>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        </div>
    );

    }
}

AuthLayout.propTypes = {
    auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    auth: state.auth
});
```

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(AuthLayout);

Login Page nested under Route > AuthLayout. I need to access the redirectUrl here so I can pass to my login function and redirect after successful login:

```
class LoginForm extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        errors: {}
    }
}

handleSubmit = values => {
    const userData = {
        email: values.email,
        password: values.password
    };

    const redirectUrl = this.props.location ? this.props.location.state.redirectUrl : "/"

    this.props.loginUser(userData, redirectUrl, this.props.history);
};

render() {

    return (
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When rendering JSX as children components of a `Route` the route props are not passed along to them.

```
<Route path="/password-reset/:reset_key?" exact>
  <AuthLayout>        // <-- no route props
    <PasswordReset /> // <-- no route props
  </AuthLayout>
</Route>
```

Use the `render` prop to access route props and explicitly pass them to the `AuthLayout` and other nested components.

```
<Route
  path="/password-reset/:reset_key?"
  exact
  render={routeProps => (
    <AuthLayout {...routeProps}>
      <PasswordReset {...routeProps} />
    </AuthLayout>
  )}
/>
```

Alternatively, you could decorate all these components with the [`withRouter`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) Higher Order Component to have the nearest `Route`'s route props injected as props.

AuthLayout:

```
import React  from 'react';
import './auth.css';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class AuthLayout extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push('/');
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="auth-background">
        <img
          alt=""
          className="logo"
          src={require("./logo1.png")}
        />
        <div id='auth-form'>
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  auth: state.auth
});

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(AuthLayout));
```

Login:

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class LoginForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      errors: {}
    }
  }

  handleSubmit = values => {
    const { history, location } = this.props;
    const { email, password } = values;
    const userData = { email, password };

    const redirectUrl = location?.state?.redirectUrl ?? "/";

    this.props.loginUser(userData, redirectUrl, history);
  };

  render() {
    ...
  }
}

export default withRouter(Login);
```

Since React class components are effectively deprecated, you may also consider converting these Class components to Function components and use the appropriate React-Router-DOM hooks.

Example:

AuthLayout:

```
import React  from 'react';
import './auth.css';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const AuthLayout = ({ children }) => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const isAuthenticated = useSelector(state => state.auth.isAuthenticated);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      history.push("/");
    }
  }, [history, isAuthenticated]);

  return (
    <div className="auth-background">
      <img
        alt=""
        className="logo"
        src={require("./logo1.png")}
      />
      <div id='auth-form'>
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AuthLayout;
```

Login:

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useHistory, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const LoginForm = () =>  {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();
  const { state } = useLocation();

  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState("");
  const [errors, setErrors] = React.useState({});

  const handleSubmit = values => {
    const { history, location } = this.props;
    const { email, password } = values;
    const userData = { email, password };

    const redirectUrl = state?.redirectUrl ?? "/";

    dispatch(loginUser(userData, redirectUrl, history));
  };

  return (
    ...
  );
}

export default Login;
```

Another alternative yet still is to refactor the routing code to render a single `AuthLayout` similar to what was done with `MainLayout`.

Example:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path={["/password-reset/:reset_key?", "/register", "/login"]}>
    <AuthLayout>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/password-reset/:reset_key?" component={PasswordReset} />
        <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      </Switch>
    </AuthLayout>
  </Route>
                      
  {/* Other MainLayout routes */}
  <Route>
    <MainLayout>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/search" component={SearchResults} />
        <Route path="/user/:user_id" component={Profile} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/settings" component={Settings} />

        <Route path="/communities/view/:community_id" component={CommunityView} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/communities/edit/:community_id" component={CommunityEdit} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/communities/new" component={CommunityNew} />
        <Route path="/communities" component={CommunityDashboard} />

        <Route path='/404' component={Error404} />
        <Route path="/" exact component={Dashboard} />
        <Redirect from='*' to='/404' />
      </Switch>
    </MainLayout>
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

Comment: I would advise against using the `withRouter` HOC only because in v6 they remove it, and upgrading is a PITA.

Comment: @Derek No strong disagreement there, I've only presented it as an option. In terms of upgrade path to v6 I'd highly recommend the 3rd option converting to Function components, it will be much more seamless conversion to `useNavigate` in RRDv6.